# "Gravitational Charge" in Newtonian Gravity in Analogy to the Electric Field

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, mass, charge

I am currently reading Carroll's GR book p. 48. There he says that

> If you like, $m_g/m_i$ can be thought of as the "gravitational charge" of the body

with the gravitational mass $m_g$ and the inertial mass $m_i$. Why? Wouldn't it make more sense to say that just $m_g$ is the gravitational charge? After all, we don't call $q/m_i$ is the electric charge of a body.

Comment: $q/m$ is called the *specific charge*.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine there is a uniform electric field $\vec{E}$ then for a particle with charge $q$ the force acting on that particle is $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$. So the acceleration will be
$$\vec{F}=\frac{q\vec{E}}{m}$$
Notice that if we double the charge the acceleration will also be doubled.

Imagine there is a uniform newtonian gravitaional field $\vec{g}$ then for a particle with inertial mass $m_i$ and gravitational mass $m_g$ the force acting on that particle is $\vec{F}=m_g\vec{g}$. So the acceleration will be
$$\vec{F}=\frac{m_g\vec{g}}{m_i}=\vec{g}\text{ since }m_i=m_g$$
Notice that if we double the $m_g$ the acceleration **will not be doubled**.

In that sense, all particles have the same gravitational charge which is +1.
The main difference compared to the electric field case is that q and m are **independent**, but $m_i$ and $m_g$ are **not independent**.